# Could not use 3dMax Model in Three.js

Tags: three.js, 3dsmax

I want to use my 3dsmax model into three.js but it does not work at all. I tried to convert my model to any appropriate format and then use it in three.js in many way, but I had no succeed.
any help would be appreciated
My 3dmax model is [here](http://www.donali.ir/Resource/Downloads?FileName=%2FFiles%2FStudents%2F3dmax%20model.max).

Comment: Please specify what you've tried (what formats?). Most of us here will not have access to 3ds Max, so providing those exported files may also help.

Comment: ... and others have access to 3ds max, but never have used Three.js ;)
I agree with Don McCurdy - there is not enough information to write a definitive answer. Nevertheless, some hints in advance: Three.js seems to support at least the [OBJ format](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader), which can be exported from 3ds max (only suitable for very simple models). Another option is to export the model as FBX from max, import it into Blender, and then export it as Three.js json from there. (See [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1591))

Comment: @DonMcCurdy yes u r right. I've tried to load my .3ds file into blender but my model was very small and far from view.I fix it now with reScale it and origin to center of mass option.But when i load it in three.js did not apeear correctly.it's characters did not stand in right place

Comment: Exporting to `.fbx` (from max) or `.gltf` (from [Blender addon](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter)) are currently the most reliable ways to get a model into three.js. What type of file are you finally loading into three.js? `.3ds`? In any case, it sounds like you'll need to post a bug on the three.js GitHub repository.